# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, database, linq, exception

I'm trying to get the price from database with linq query but this exception apperas constantly, I dont know why.
The data types are the same, both decimals.

```
newOrder.Cmimi = Convert.ToDecimal(context.Produktets.Where(c=>c.Emri_Produktit == prodName[0]).Select(c => c.Cmimi).First());
```

Can someone help please ?????

Comment: Assign `prodName[0]` to variable outside the query and use that variable inside.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using array indexer in a linq query and linq to entities is failing to translate `prodName[0]` into SQL. You can try to store the value in a variable and use it in the query instead:

```
var name = prodName[0];
newOrder.Cmimi = Convert.ToDecimal(context.Produktets
                                          .Where(c => c.Emri_Produktit == name)
                                          .Select(c => c.Cmimi).First());
```

Comment: This does not only apply to Arrays but to every data structure with an indexer (e.g. Lists)